# Accessing Flash functions through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, internet-explorer

I use the following jQuery code to access functions in my SWF (FP 10.1 SWF embedded via SWFObject):

```
$('#FlashApp')[0].someFunc();
```

This works fine in every browser.. except for Internet Explorer (surprise!). Surely, the point of jQuery is to make this code work across all browsers? I'd really rather not write extra code to check for IE.

How can I talk to my SWF in a browser independent way?

Comment: jQuery is primarily focussed on core HTML DOM functionality, it makes no claims about cross browser Flash functionality.  try Matt's thing though, I bet its an IE issue that has nothing to do with jquery.

Comment: It seems that this has more to do with the fact that the SWF was hidden (via CSS) during the call.

Comment: I've seen this before, Franky-D. Not fun.

Comment: I did find, however, that you can achieve the same effect by having the SWF have a width of 1 and height of 1, and set the size to appropriate when you're ready to show the SWF. That way, IE thinks the swf is visible and responds correctly.

Comment: Indeed, but you still have to be careful: some browsers will reload the SWF when you resize it! More fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was due to IE not being able to talk to an invisible SWF.

Answer (score 1):

Dousn't sound like a jQuery problem.  Try the following in IE to see if you get the same results:

```
document.getElementById('FlashApp').someFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need External Interface

http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/externalinterface/